# Get content of certain xml node based on its attribute in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

I have an XML sheet I want to extract content from.

This is how the XML looks like:

```
<scores sport="soccer">
<script/>
   <category name="England: Premier League" id="1204" file_group="england">
      <matches date="Aug 24" formatted_date="24.08.2013">
         <match status="11:45" date="Aug 24" formatted_date="24.08.2013" time="11:45" static_id="1483470" fix_id="1395250" id="1556405">
            <localteam name="Fulham" goals="?" id="9175"/>
            <visitorteam name="Arsenal" goals="?" id="9002"/>
            <events/>
            <ht score=""/>
         </match>
      <match status="14:00" date="Aug 24" formatted_date="24.08.2013" time="14:00" static_id="1483469" fix_id="1395249" id="1556404">
            <localteam name="Everton" goals="?" id="9158"/>
            <visitorteam name="West Brom" goals="?" id="9426"/>
            <events/>
            <ht score=""/>
         </match>
      </matches>
   </category>
</scores>
```

What I want to to is to get the attributes of the nodes as strings in PHP. For example, I want to get the localteam-name and visitorsteam-name for the match with 1556404 as ID (and only that mach)

Is it possible to solve this easily?

Dan

Comment: Yes it is possible. It's also easily possible. But: This question has been asked before. This website works the following: You've got a question so you first search for the existing answer. Easy, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry guys, first question asked at Stack.. I got suggestions when I wrote the questions but none of them answered the question for me.

Comment: Well, list them all each one, explain what you did (and why you thought it must have worked), show what it did instead and why that does not suit you. provide reference. Unless you do it's not clear which detail you ask about that has not been answered already. So you need to help us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://url.com/xml');

$localTeamName = $xml
    ->xpath('/scores/category/matches/match[@id=1556404]/localteam/@name');
```

Comment: $string is the XML url? How should that look like? I wrote $string = "http://www.url.com/xml"); but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, it's the XML itself. Use [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to load XML from a URL.

Comment: @AlonGubkin: Well, you perhaps need to record that on mp3 because if mistderdh is not able to read the manual entry about that object, he can't be able to read your comment as well. So why not provide a recording?

Comment: I don't get it to work. I only get this error message: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/hotels/public_html/backend/index.php:29 Stack trace: #0 /home/hotels/public_html/backend/index.php(29): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('? ? ? ? ? ...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/hotels/public_html/backend/index.php on line 29

Comment: Make sure you have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`